# Locale is not changing for Spring 2.5 i18n project

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I am trying to apply I18n for the existing Spring 2.5 application. The below is the application-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName">
        <value>SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE</value>
    </property>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>
                classpath:Classification-System.properties
            </value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
   <property name="basenames">
      <list>
         <value>
             classpath:classification/Strings
         </value>
     </list>
  </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US" />
</bean> 
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

If i login the application, if i apply lang=es_ES for the url, it's showing english locale strings only eventhough locale is spanish
I configured Strings.properties,Strings_es_ES.properties, Strings_en_GB.properties in classification folder of src/resouce/ with common key and diferent values.

Any one could you help me?

my web.xml is

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">
<filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInView</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>classificationSessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>flushMode</param-name>
        <param-value>AUTO</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>classifierweb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openSessionInView</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>classifierweb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

could you pls any one help me?

here is classifierweb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
    <property name="defaultHandler" ref="defaultController" />
</bean>
<bean id="defaultController"
    class="com.billshrink.ml.classification.web.controller.DefaultController"></bean>

<bean id="classificationController"
    class="com.billshrink.ml.classification.web.controller.ClassificationController">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="classificationSessionFactory" />
    <property name="classificationDao" ref="classificationDao" />
    <property name="classifier" ref="classifier" />
    <property name="classificationExportable" ref="classificationExportable" />
    <property name="dataSources">
        <list>
            <ref bean="merchantsClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="categoryClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="cityStateClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="ageRangeClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="priceRangeClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="nationalityClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="chunkedMerchantsClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="chunkedCategoryClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="chunkedCityStateClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="chunkedAgeRangeClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="chunkedPriceRangeClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="chunkedNationalityClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="chunkedChannelClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="merchantChannelExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="chunkedPhoneGeoClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="chunkedTransactionTypeClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="phoneGeoClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="transactionTypeClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="cityExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="stateExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="merchantCategoryExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="channelClassificationExpressionDataSource" />
            <ref bean="chunkedLocationBasedMerchantExpressionFilter" />
            <ref bean="chunkedCategoryExpressionFilter" />
            <ref bean="chunkedCityStateCategoryExpressionFilter" />
            <ref bean="chunkedAgeRangeExpressionFilter" />
            <ref bean="chunkedPriceRangeExpressionFilter" />
            <ref bean="chunkedNationalityExpressionFilter" />
            <ref bean="chunkedChannelExpressionFilter" />
            <ref bean="chunkedPhoneGeoCategoryExpressionFilter"/>
            <ref bean="chunkedTransactionTypeCategoryExpressionFilter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="luceneUtil" ref="luceneUtil" />
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="classificationCacheManager" />
    <property name="displayNames">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
            <property name="sourceMap">
                <map>
                    <entry key="type" value="Type" />
                    <entry key="dimension" value="Dimension" />
                    <entry key="name" value="Name" />
                    <entry key="displayName" value="Display Name" />
                    <entry key="searchExpression" value="Search Expression" />
                    <entry key="phoneNumbers" value="Phone Numbers" />
                    <entry key="areaCodes" value="Area Codes" />
                    <entry key="CATEGORY" value="Category" />
                    <entry key="AGE_RANGE" value="Age Range" />
                    <entry key="PRICE_RANGE" value="Price Range" />
                    <entry key="NATIONALITY" value="Nationality" />
                    <entry key="LOCATION_TYPE" value="Location Type" />
                    <entry key="CHANNEL" value="Channel" />
                    <entry key="TRANSACTION_TYPE" value="Transaction Type" />
                    <entry key="zips" value="Zips" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="displayAttributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="CITY_STATE">
                <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean">
                    <property name="sourceList">
                        <list>
                            <value>zips</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="displayDimensions">
        <map>
            <entry key="MERCHANT">
                <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean">
                    <property name="sourceList">
                        <list>
                            <value>CATEGORY</value>
                            <value>AGE_RANGE</value>
                            <value>PRICE_RANGE</value>
                            <value>NATIONALITY</value>
                            <value>LOCATION_TYPE</value>
                            <value>CHANNEL</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="attributeNames">
        <map>
            <entry key="phoneNumbers" value="phoneNumber" />
            <entry key="areaCodes" value="areaCode" />
            <entry key="ageRange" value="ageRange" />
            <entry key="priceRange" value="ageRange" />
            <entry key="nationality" value="nationality" />
            <entry key="zips" value="zips" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="metaDataDimensions">
        <list>
            <value>CATEGORY</value>
            <value>AGE_RANGE</value>
            <value>PRICE_RANGE</value>
            <value>NATIONALITY</value>
            <value>LOCATION_TYPE</value>
            <value>CHANNEL</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="com.billshrink.ml.classification.web.controller.TransactionController">
    <property name="classifier" ref="classifier" />
    <property name="classificationDao" ref="classificationDao" />
    <property name="tokenNames" ref="tokenNames" />
    <property name="classifiedTokenNames" ref="classifiedTokenNames" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenNames" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
    <property name="sourceMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="merchant" value="Merchant" />
            <entry key="phoneNumber" value="Phone Number" />
            <entry key="location" value="Location" />
            <entry key="city" value="City" />
            <entry key="state" value="State" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="classifiedTokenNames" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean">
    <property name="sourceMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="MERCHANT" value="Merchant" />
            <entry key="zips" value="Zip" />
            <entry key="city" value="City" />
            <entry key="state" value="State" />
            <entry key="CITY_STATE" value="City State" />
            <entry key="CATEGORY" value="Category" />
            <entry key="AGE_RANGE" value="Age Range" />
            <entry key="PRICE_RANGE" value="Price Range" />
            <entry key="NATIONALITY" value="Nationality" />
            <entry key="CHANNEL" value="Channel" />
            <entry key="TRANSACTION_TYPE" value="Transaction Type" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="com.billshrink.ml.classification.web.controller.ClassificationMonitorController">
    <property name="db" ref="classificationMonitorDb" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="com.billshrink.ml.classification.web.controller.TokenizerController">
    <property name="tokenizer" ref="transactionTokenizer" />
    <property name="tokenNames" ref="tokenNames" />
</bean>

<bean class="com.billshrink.ml.classification.web.controller.FeedsController">
    <property name="classificationDao" ref="classificationDao" />
    <property name="classificationController" ref="classificationController" />
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
   <property name="basenames">
      <list>
         <value>
             classpath:classification/Strings
         </value>
     </list>
  </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US" />
</bean> 
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I assume you have it in `src/main/resources` (assuming you use maven). Also you have it in the `application-context.xml` where is this file loaded? Is this loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` if not it doesn't do anything (please post your web.xml).

Comment: Post your `classifierweb-servlet.xml`. Basically your configuration in your `application-context.xml` (the `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` and `LocaleChangeInterceptor` don't do anything they aren't detected by the `DispatcherServlet` those should be in the `classifierweb-servlet.xml`

Comment: i tried by placing in classifierweb-servlet.xml, but no luck. please find classifierweb-servlet.xml code

Comment: You have 2 `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` one with an interceptor and no default and one with a default but no interceptor. Merge them into one.